# Why does log print "module MAY be using inspect.stack"

Tags: python, python-2.7, inspect

When I build/install my package, the line `[package.module]: module MAY be using inspect.stack` prints to the log. It doesn't preface this with "warning" or "error", but it seems like a strange thing to print in the midst of the other information (e.g., "creating...egg", "Extracting...to...site-packages".

Is there some reason that I shouldn't be using inspect.stack() within my package? If there is no reason, then why does this one function (out of the hundreds used) result in this strange notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning message, printed via `log.warn` in `bdist_egg.py`.  It probably should include the word 'warning', and I'm not sure why it doesnt.

The warning is raised by `scan_module`, which is used to determine if the package can be zip compressed or not.  You'd probably have to check the mailing list to see why stack introspection prevents compressed eggs, but at a guess I'd say zip compression might mess with line number information handed to `inspect`.  Referencing `__file__` or `__path__` will also get the package flagged as not zip safe.